# Ignoring last-of-type in WebBrowser

Tags: .net, browser

I'm using a Windows.System.Forms.Webbrowser and the document text contains

```
...<style type="text/css">
Table {
    page-break-after: always;
}
table:last-of-type {
    page-break-after: auto
}
</style>...
```

as soon as call ShowPrintPreviewDialog() to show the print preview dialog, it appears to be ignoring

```
table:table:last-of-type
```

because the last page in the document is blank.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Does IE on the same computer ignore it as well, or is it just the WebBrowser control?

Comment: @BoltClock - yes,IE is installed on the same computer (IE9).  I have tested this in IE and it works as you would expect however not in the WebBrowser!!